# A space having exactly three coverings up to equivalence

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

Q: Give an example of a topological space having exactly 3 coverings up to equivalence (including a covering by the space itself).

Proof: There is a theorem that says that given a topological manifold $M$ with a universal cover, the coverings are determined up to isomorphism by the conjugacy classes of subgroups of $\pi_{1}(M)$ (i.e. Topological Manifolds by Lee, Thm 12.18)

So let's take a group with exactly three subgroups up to conjugacy, so a group with 1 proper subgroup up to conjugay. A bit of thought leads to taking $\mathbb{Z}_{4}$ since this is Abelian so no need to worry about conjugacy and has three subgroups, $\mathbb{Z}_{4}, \{0\}, \langle 2\rangle$. Hence there are exactly three coverings for any topological space with $\pi_{1}(M)=\mathbb{Z}_{4}$.

Hence we construct such a space as follows. Take a representation: $\mathbb{Z}_{4}=\langle a : a^{4}=1 \rangle$. Form the $1$-skeleton of a cell complex by taking the circle, and attach a disk by wraping the boundary $4$ times around the circle.

So first question, does this look alright? Second question, is there any way to imagine this thing? More precisely, can I embed this in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$? My first instinct says no, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Of course the theorem, in the form you've stated it, can't be used because the space you describe isn't a manifold. However, luckily the theorem holds for more general spaces (see most introductory algebraic topology texts for the sufficient conditions). Other than this small point, the proof looks fine to me.

Comment: If you want the space to be a manifold, you may be interested to know that every finitely generated group can be realised as the fundamental group of a $4$-manifold. See, for instance, [this MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/15411/finite-generated-group-realized-as-fundamental-group-of-manifolds).

Comment: Thanks, I did not need it to be a Manifold, but it is good to know it would work there too!